# How to send save multiple ng-options json data?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am new to ng-options

Here I attached fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/soumyagangamwar/htj1wy0g/

I have a JSON data in my controller

```
$scope.tables= [{
                "label": 'table1'
                },
                {
                "label": 'table2'
                },
                {
                "label": 'table3'
                }];

 $scope.columns = [{
                   "columnName" : 'colname1'
                   },
                   {
                   "columnName" : 'colname2'
                   },
                   {
                    "columnName" : 'colname3'
                   }];
$scope.addoperation = function(join) {
     $scope.operationInfo.push(join);
     console.log($scope.operationInfo , '$scope.operationInfo ')

 }
```

my view is

```
 </select>
<select class="form-control" ng-model="join.targetTable" 
        ng-options = "ttabel.label for ttabel in tables">

</select>
```

```
 </select>

 <select class="form-control" ng-model="join.targetColumn" 
 ng-options = "tcolumn.columnName for tcolumn in columns">
</select>

<a ng-click="addoperation(join)">add</a>
<br>
<table class="table bordered">
<tr>
<th>Source Tabel</th>
<th>Source Column</th>
<th>Target Tabel</th>
<th>Target Column</th>
</tr>
  <tr>{{operationInfo}}</tr>
  <tr ng-repeat = "info in operationInfo">
   <td>{{info.sourceTable.label}}</td>
   <td>{{info.sourceColumn.columnName}}</td>
   <td>{{info.targetTable.label}}</td>
   <td>{{info.targetColumn.columnName}}</td>
</tr>
```

If I click **add** link then click fun I am pushing those values in one empty array. and with help of ng-repeat, I am displaying it in form of table.

The problem is in after the first click when I change the drop down values then the printed table values are also changing.

my requirement is when I click to add the link I want to push it one array and displaying that array in that table.In second push I want to show previous and present values

Comment: write full script of your controller

Answer (score 0):

try to stringify and parse your json object before pushing it to your array

Comment: that is not problem. I want save the values. instead of that it's updating

Comment: $scope.operationInfo.push(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(join))); use this in ur function   and var tempData=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify($scope.operationInfo));  use tempData for store

Answer (score 0):

As you are referring the same object that's why the printed table values are also changing. Try to make a deep copy of your object then push.

Comment: @SoumyaGangamwar .. http://jsfiddle.net/er_markar/htj1wy0g/1/ check this